# Why my list only shows the last value after looping through it?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a list and have added values to it but it only shows the last value added after extracting values from it. why?

```
DataTable dt = ClsContractor.GetContractorsPasswordsWhereEqualsCNIC();
Contractors c = new Contractors();

DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    string password = Utility.Decrypt(Convert.ToString(r["Password"])).Trim();
    string CNIC = Convert.ToString(r["CNIC"]).Trim();
    c.NewPwd = Convert.ToString(r["NewPwd"]).Trim();         

    if (password == CNIC)
    {
        c.ContractorID = Convert.ToInt32(r["ContractorID"]).ToInt32();
        lstContractorsID.Add(c);
        Utility.Msg_Success(Master, "Pwd: " + password + " and CNIC: " + CNIC + " matched :" + i++.ToString());            

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's due to the fact that you are overwriting the "Contractor c" object.

```
Contractors c = new Contractors();
```

should be declared inside the foreach loop.